# Incorrect stock prices showing up from YQL request (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that fetches current stock prices from YQL (using Alamofire):

```
func stockFetcher(completion: @escaping ([String]?) -> Void) {
Alamofire.request(stockUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
        let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        if let appleStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Ask"].string {
            prices.append(appleStockPrice)
        }
        if let googleStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][1]["Ask"].string {
            prices.append(googleStockPrice)
        }
        if let twitterStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][2]["Ask"].string {
            prices.append(twitterStockPrice)
        }
        if let teslaStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][3]["Ask"].string {
            prices.append(teslaStockPrice)
        }
        if let samsungStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][4]["Ask"].string {
            prices.append(samsungStockPrice)
        }
        completion(prices)
        print(json)
    }
}
}
```

Here's the JSON that's returned, everything looks good except the null for Twitter but that's a separate issue:

```
{
"query" : {
"created" : "2017-01-11T16:34:51Z",
"results" : {
  "quote" : [
    {
      "symbol" : "AAPL",
      "YearLow" : "89.4700",
      "YearHigh" : "119.3600",
      "Ask" : "119.1100"
    },
    {
      "symbol" : "GOOG",
      "YearLow" : "663.06",
      "YearHigh" : "816.68",
      "Ask" : "805.08"
    },
    {
      "symbol" : "TWTR",
      "YearLow" : "13.730",
      "YearHigh" : "25.250",
      "Ask" : null
    },
    {
      "symbol" : "TSLA",
      "YearLow" : "141.0500",
      "YearHigh" : "269.3400",
      "Ask" : "227.8600"
    },
    {
      "symbol" : "SSNLF",
      "YearLow" : "1000.00",
      "YearHigh" : "1600.00",
      "Ask" : null
    }
  ]
},
"count" : 5,
"lang" : "en;q=1.0"
  }
}
```

In my tableview I display the prices like so (in cellForRow):

```
    stockFetcher(completion: {
        (prices) -> Void in

        if (prices?.count)! > indexPath.row + 1 {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Current Stock Price: \(prices![indexPath.row])"
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "No data found"
        }
    })
```

And the first 3 show up with the correct prices, but Tesla shows whatever Apple's current price is (in this case 119) and Samsung shows whatever Google's price is (in this case 804) - seems like the first 3 prices show up then just start repeating.

Can anyone see where the issue is?

EDIT: cellForRow

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CompanyCell

    // Labels
    cell.textLabel?.text = companyNames[indexPath.row]

    // Detail labels
    stockFetcher(completion: {
        (prices) -> Void in

        if (prices?.count)! > indexPath.row + 1 {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Current Stock Price: \(prices![indexPath.row])"
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "No data found"
        }
    })

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This won't work. UITableView reuses cells, so you need to use the delegate methods in UITableViewDataSource. You can read about how to use UITableView here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a bit? I am aware of UITableView's delegate methods and am using them.

Comment: Can you add your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath method into the question? It'll give your code more context, thanks!

Comment: Done! Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @geoffrey-wiseman is correct, what you have is a race condition.

Comment: i would parse also the company name from the json and not assume that the order is always the same. then you are more flexible what you do with the data. use a data struct and put this in a array like a struct Stock(company:"GOOG", ask:123)

Answer (score 0):

Your `stockFetcher` does something asynchronously (a network request with a completion block) while the completion block retains a reference to a cell that may be re-used.

By the time Alamofire returns with data, that cell may be being used somewhere else. You shouldn't hang on on to the cell reference and do something async. You should, instead, asynchronously fetch the data outside of the table view datasource method and then, when `cellForRowAt` is triggered, simply read from the stored data.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. If I understand correctly (still learning the ropes), you're suggesting moving the stockFetcher completion block outside of cellForRow then set the detailTextLabels from that data?

Comment: fetch the data outside - then set the prices somewhere in the tableDataSource and then call reloadData on the tableView to trigger a repopulate the table from this array

Comment: with your current code you call the stockfetcher for each table cell again (and also when you scroll the table and the cell gets repainted) you should avoid this and call it outside the table only one time (also to avoid get banned for calling too much time the api). also you should cache the result to be api friendly and to avoid to many calls to an api

Comment: Right -- call stockFetcher somewhere when you're not rendering the cells, store the data somewhere, like in a view controller property and populate the cells from the stored data.